# Why is my program terminated when calling "OpenAsync()"?

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, ado.net, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect to a database that is running on MariaDB by using  [MySqlConnector](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/index.html). However, if I execute the basic code snippet from the specified website, my program terminates as soon as it comes to the asynchronous opening of the database connection (figured out by debugging). In general, the console window just pops on the screen and then immediately closes again.

I installed the MySqlConnector as described [here](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/overview/installing/) via the NuGet package manager.

The synchronous versions of the asynchronous methods work without any problems, I receive the data as expected. A connection to another database did not work either.

This is my program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                    
        doSomeStuff();            
    }

    public static async void doSomeStuff()
    {
        var connString = "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=password;Database=mysql";

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();                

            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT host FROM mysql.user", conn))
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Why does this happen? Is there anything I'm missing? Perhaps something concerning the configuration on the server side?

Targeted Framework: .NET Framework 4.7.1
MySqlConnector version: 0.53.0
MariaDB version: 10.3.14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not awaiting the execution of the method `doSomeStuff`, so when it arrives to the first await, it returns the control to the main, and since there are no things left to do in main it returns ending the program.

You got 2 options here,

1. Is to run a main async awaiting a Task.delay(-1), execute first the method you have, and since you are awaiting a task that will never end you will get the job done.
2. Call your method like this doSomeStuff().GetAwaiter().GetResult() . This will await for the method to execute what it needs to and then return to the main thread. In order to achieve this you should change the signature of your method for an async task instead of an async void. (Best Option if using older c# versions)
3. Option 3 (best option if c# 7.1 or newer) by MickyD

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078498/10513564

Comment: 1) What would waiting indefinately accomplish? 2) You can't call `GetAwaiter()` on an `async` method which is marked as `async void` as there is no `Task` to await.  You'll get a compile error

Comment: @MickyD First of all i do agree with you, you cant get an awaiter on an async method, so i ll edit my answer. As for the indefinately delay it would be in the case you do keep the course of action of using the async void, because as is not ending ever, then it wont matter that you are not awaiting the doSomeStuff(); ( Im not saying its the best solution, as a matter of fact i think the task option is the best one here, but it is a possibility). I will edit my answer accordingly to both things to make it clearer.

Comment: Interesting point.. In 3.1 I didn't have to await it and it worked for some reason, but in 6.0 it just ended right away. Not sure if there was some change that's causing this. But your answer helped me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You biggest issue might be using the **async void** method, what happens with async voids is that when errors occur, your method silently dies(crashes app depending on location) and never tell you what the issue is,

A few article on the net explain this principle, on such is at https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

> In C#, async void methods are a scourge upon your code. To understand
>   why, I recommend this detailed Stephen Cleary article, Best Practices
>   in Asynchronous Programming. In short, exceptions thrown when calling
>   an async void method isn’t handled the same way as awaiting a Task and
>   will crash the process. Not a great experience.
>
> Recently, I found another reason to avoid async void methods. While
>   investigating a bug, I noticed that the unit test that should have
>   ostensibly failed because of the bug passed with flying colors. That’s
>   odd. There was no logical reason for the test to pass given the bug.
>
> Then I noticed that the return type of the method was async void. On a
>   hunch I changed it to async Task and it started to fail. Ohhhhh snap!

The are a few others that you can check on the net, async voids are mostly used for events, try changing the void into a Task and the error you are expecting will popup(at least you will have a starting point to figure out why your connection is failing)

Also if you are running an asynchronous in a synchronous one, then just do a `Task.Run(() => doSomeStuff()).Result;`

That will force your method to run to completion in a synchronous method if you do not have access to the await keyword

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are using **.NET Framework 4.7.1** you might want to consider forcing **C# 7.1** in your project and make use of `async Main()`.  It leads to much **cleaner** code without any ugly `GetResult()`/`Result`/`Sleep`/`Task.Delay`.

e.g.

```
class Program
{
    // Specify C# 7.1 in the project's Properties.Build.Advanced.Language Version field
    // in order to use 'static async Task Main'
    static async Task Main(string[] args) // <--- Note the async Task
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for 3 seconds");

        // the await prevents the app from exiting prematurely
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));  
    }
}
```

If you get a compile error, you may need to force C# 7.1:

[image]

So, in your case change your code to:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await doSomeStuff();
}

public static async Task doSomeStuff() // <--- make it Task so it can be await'ed
{
    var connString = "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=password;Database=mysql";

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT host FROM mysql.user", conn))
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }


    Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

### async void

Though **mahlatse's** warning about `async void` has merrit, it doesn't apply to your specific problem whereby **the application is exiting prematurely** due to **not waiting for tasks to complete** as opposed to an application exiting prematurely due to *an exception being thrown from an `async void` method*.  Assuming the only difference between your synchronous code and the asynchorous code is the `async` and not say database connections your code should **not** be faulting.